# How to post a string to web server url in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

How can I post a string(i.e) a word to web server url in iphone sdk?

Some sample codes or tutorials would be appreciated.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post the string to webservice in so many ways, In those one is 
Using Rest protocol:

It has two sub types, HTTP GET, HTTP POST. The Http Get is simple.

You can add the value to the attribute and you can directly call the service.
Check the following code.

```
NSString *url = @"http://123.456.789.0?action=get_movies";
```

Here the I am passing the get_movies string to the server to the action attribute.
and then follow the code for requesting to server.

```
NSURL *reqUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:reqUrl];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSStringEncoding responseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
if ([response textEncodingName]) {
CFStringEncoding cfStringEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)[response textEncodingName]);
if (cfStringEncoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
    responseEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfStringEncoding); 
    }
}
[reqUrl release];
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:responseEncoding];
```

the dataString is the responseString from the server. You can use that.

Regards,

Satya.

Comment: how to check if device has internet connection or not?

Answer (score 5):

This may help you, although I havent tested it:

```
NSMutableString *httpBodyString;
NSURL *url;
NSMutableString *urlString;

httpBodyString=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Name=The Big Bopper&Subject=Hello Baby&MsgBody=...You knooow what I like...Chantilly lace..."];
urlString=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.somedomain.com/contactform.php"];

url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
[urlString release];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[url release];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[httpBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
[httpBodyString release];

NSURLConnection *connectionResponse = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

if (!connectionResponse)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"--------- Request submitted ---------");
    NSLog(@"connection: %@ method: %@, encoded body: %@, body: %a", connectionResponse, [urlRequest HTTPMethod], [urlRequest HTTPBody], httpBodyString);
    NSLog(@"New connection retain count: %d", [connectionResponse retainCount]);
    responseData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSLog(@"response", responseData);
}
```

Source: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6341-help-executing-http-url-post-variables.html

Comment: Also try "PUT" in the above if "POST" does not work (i.e. is not the practiced method).